# Difficulty in creating command for right alignment of text

Tags: macros, pdftex

I am trying to create a command for right alignment of text.
The text must be kept on the same line if it fits on the line, else it must flow to the next line but must keep the alignment (right aligned). Currently I can do these with two separate commands, like:

```
\renewcommand{\marks}[1]{\ \newline\hfill\textbf{[#1\hphantom{a}marks]}}
```

or

```
\renewcommand{\marks}[1]{\ \hfill\textbf{[#1\hphantom{a}marks]}}
```

However, I am unable to combine them. That is,

1. if I use the first command then it puts a new line even if there is space on the same line.
2. if I use the second command then it puts the `marks` towards the **left** on the next line if space is unavailable on the same line.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will solve your problem:

```
\renewcommand{\marks}[1]{%
  \unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50\null\nobreak
  \hfil\textbf{[#1\hphantom{a}marks]}%
  \parfillskip 0pt\finalhyphendemerits0}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked just fine. Can you please explain what is happening here.

Comment: These just process your request with penalties and parameters.

Answer (score 1):

This implementation allows that any text following the `\marks` argument gets pushed onto a new line, rather than get tacked onto the same line as the `\marks` argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\marks[1]{\ \hfil\allowbreak\mbox{}\hfil\mbox{\bfseries #1}\break}

\begin{document}
Here is the first text. \marks{Here is the second text.} And here is the next text.

Here is the first text which is also quite longer. \marks{Here is the second text.} And here is the next text.

Here is the first text which is also quite longer.. \marks{Here is the second text.} And here is the next text.

Here is the first text which is more than quite a bit longer. \marks{Here is the second text.} And here is the next text.
\end{document}
```

[image]